# Password_hash() need of pre-hashing before submit?

Tags: javascript, php, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

I'm using the PHP 5.5+ password_hash() function to hash my passwords before storage in the database. So far so good.

What I am a bit uncertain of is the need of pre-hashing the password that it sent from the form to my PHP script.

Now the form submit procedure is (in short terms) done like this:

1. HTML file which contains the form calls the controller script in form method=".." ->
2. Controller script recieves the call and picks the correct function ->
3. function execution and storage to database.

So basically the call is sent through three files from submit to storage.

I am thinking that somewhere along the line the data could be hijacked and seen in plain view since the hashing is done in the third and final file.

Should I be worried and somehow hash the password with some JavaScript during the initial submission of the form or is it safe? The final site will most likely use an SSL certificate but still I'm not 100% sure if I am safe or not.

Comment: If you hash the password in the browser before sending it to the webserver, then hash again on the server, you're almost certainly weakening the password that is eventually stored because the initial hash will reduce the entropy of the password.... and if you're sending via SSL, then your security between browser and webserver is handled by SSL, so no need to hash in the browser

Comment: All PHP scripts are executed in one interpreter instance. A non-issue is mostly how PHP reads the form/POST data; if there *was* a file attachemen a temporary file got created (unlikely for most login forms). You're probably asking about the unhashed password being transferred via HTTP? That's only solvable per TLS.

Comment: I will then go with the solution I have today and hope for the best. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concerns about hijacking the password between controllers are superfluous :

For an attacker to hijack the password while it's passed between different controllers it would mean the attacker has to be able to read the memory of the PHP process, which would require root privileges. If the attacker has root privileges, you have a bigger problem and your solution won't save you because that same attacker can also modify the PHP files to remove your "protection".

As for hijacking the password while it's flying through the Internet, the only solution is to use HTTPS - whatever Javascript cryptography/hashing you would do is pointless since an eavesdropper is also able to alter the page while it's being transmitted and serve a modified version of it without the additional "security" you added; there are many questions about trying to secure a login form without HTTPS on Security.SE, check them out :

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73917/techniques-to-make-a-login-page-safe-without-using-ssl
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37655/build-a-secure-channel-without-ssl-tls
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41845/login-security-without-ssl
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/what-is-the-best-way-of-securing-a-website-logon-without-ssl-or-preshared-keys

Comment: the question is about the first step when the password is posted. This is plain text unless SSL is used.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans - If the password is sent to the webserver over an SSL connection, then it isn't being sent in plaintext

Comment: I'm not saying that you don't have to use SSL. My comment at this answer was to support my downvote.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - Thank you for an thorough and informative answer. I will go as I am today and hope for the best. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - A sniffer might not be able to alter the page, in which case client side hashing would be beneficial. It would also hide the plain text password from anything between the client and server such as proxies, application firewalls, etc. any of which could be compromised. Not to mention potential log files. I would also like to add that SSL is not  100% secure. I'm not talking about cracking keys, but there are ways to circumvent it. See "sslstrip" as an example.

Comment: @JoAreBy A sniffer wouldn't need to alter the page, he could just replay the captured password and impersonate the user. I say this is just a waste of time, I don't see any real reason why you wouldn't want to use HTTPS today.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Good point, but you can prevent replay attacks by implementing some kind of challenge-response. It's not meant as an alternative to HTTPS. I'm just arguing that HTTPS is no silver bullet, and that there might be benefit of doing additional security.